# How to test a function with internal state?

Tags: c, unity-test-framework

I am unit testing the following function, using Ceedling.

```
bool PRM_inputVoltageIsGood(ParameterHandle_t p, float voltage) {
    static bool voltageGoodHyst = false;
    /* Check if voltage has risen above ON point. */
    if ((!voltageGoodHyst) && (voltage > p->vin_on)) {
        voltageGoodHyst = true;
    }
    /* Check if voltage has fallen below OFF point. */
    else if ((voltageGoodHyst) && (voltage < p->vin_off)) {
        voltageGoodHyst = false;
    }
    return voltageGoodHyst;
}
```

With tests like the following:

```
void test_PRM_inputVoltageIsGood_should_stayAtFalse_before_risingOverVInOn(void)
{
    float i;
    p->vin_on = 10.0;
    p->vin_off = 5.0;
    for (i = 0; i <= p->vin_on; ++i)
        TEST_ASSERT_FALSE(PRM_inputVoltageIsGood(p, i));
}

void test_PRM_inputVoltageIsGood_should_switchToTrue_when_risingOverVInOn(void)
{
    p->vin_on = 10.0;
    p->vin_off = 5.0;
    TEST_ASSERT_FALSE(PRM_inputVoltageIsGood(p, p->vin_on));
    TEST_ASSERT_TRUE(PRM_inputVoltageIsGood(p, (p->vin_on + 1)));
}

void test_PRM_inputVoltageIsGood_should_stayAtTrue_before_fallingUnderVInOff(void)
{
    float i = 0;
    p->vin_on = 10.0;
    p->vin_off = 5.0;
    for (i = p->vin_on + 1; i >= p->vin_off; --i)
        TEST_ASSERT_TRUE(PRM_inputVoltageIsGood(p, i));
}

void test_PRM_inputVoltageIsGood_should_switchToFalse_when_fallingUnderVInOff(void)
{
    p->vin_on = 10.0;
    p->vin_off = 5.0;
    TEST_ASSERT_TRUE(PRM_inputVoltageIsGood(p, p->vin_off));
    TEST_ASSERT_FALSE(PRM_inputVoltageIsGood(p, (p->vin_off - 1)));
}
```

The function has internal state in the form of the function-scope static variable `voltageGoodhyst` (because the output is hysteretic).

Because of the hysteresis my tests have to occur in a certain order. which is bad. I kind of want to avoid having to make the variable have any wider scope as this is the only function concerned with this functionality (the object pointed to by `ParametersHandle_t` conforms to a specific layout so I can't add it there either)... Is there any other way I can adjust this or write tests so that they are not required to execute in a specific order?

Comment: Add a `bool resetState` pararameter to the function..

Comment: That's why they say state is bad.

Comment: @n.m., yep, yet state is a real world phenomenon all the same (and some voltage systems have it)

Comment: It is *imperative* to handle state in a clean civilised manner :) and not make thing worse still by hiding it. Make it an additional function argument perhaps.

Comment: I had a painful time testing functions with static variables so I know that feeling. It's not always possible to make the architectures/developers change their code/design.

Answer (score 1):

One tactic would be to create your tests such that *after* you run them, the static variable will have the same value.

For example, since it's initialized as `static bool voltageGoodHyst = false;`, every time you run a unit test that changes it to `true`, send a final request `PRM_inputVoltageIsGood(p, 0)` to make the static variable false.

This way, regardless of the order the unit tests execute, you will know what the static variable is false when you enter the next test.